# How to use current object in a computed observable? -- Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a `foreach` data-binding on an array.

I want to access the current object or place in the computed observable (as it happens with the `click` data-binding).

---

Example:

Here is my View:

```html
<tbody data-bind='foreach: items'>
  <tr data-bind="attr: {class:$root.changeClass()}">
    <td data-bind='text: name'></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And, here is the view-model:

```js
function model() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray(itemArray);
  self.changeClass = ko.computed(function(data) {
    //code that depends on data
    return 'someClass';
  });
};
```

---

I'm a beginner. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just call a function no need of computed . try this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24692/ . cheers

Comment: Is it not like only `click` data-binding passes the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

**View:**

```
<table data-bind='foreach: items'>
  <tr data-bind="attr: {class:$root.changeClass($data)}">
    <td data-bind='text: $data'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Css :**

```
 .classEven{
     color:blue;
    }

 .classOdd{
       color:red;
    }
```

**viewModel:**

```
function model() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray([1,2,3]);
  self.changeClass =function(data) {
    //code that depends on data
      if(data%2) return 'classEven';
      else return 'classOdd';
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new model()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

working sample fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24694/)

Comment: when I passed the `$data` variable to a computed observable, I received a warning message asking me to make the computed observable 'writable'? Why so?
Thanks a lot, by the way.

Comment: don't use computeds use normal function as mentioned above .

Comment: But.. I need to change the class whenever `$data` is present in an array.
Basically, I am trying to disable the button `Add to Cart` that adds the item to a `cart` array. And the button should be disable only if the item is present in the `cart` array. Hope you understood the problem. Thanks!

Comment: something like this ??? http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24698/ . when `$data` value in null or undefined or empty your button will be enabled as you said  . cheers